# Android Beginner. I need help setting multiple alarms from SQLite databases in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Okay my program is about scheduling Homework times. So the program will prompt the user for subject and time. The Subjects and Times gets saved in the Database. When the times comes, the alarm should ring. MY PROBLEM IS my program only works for one alarm. The last alarm set overrides the earlier set alarms, I added the request code in the second parameter of PendingIntent.getbroadcast, but somehow my program still sets only ONE alarm. My program is given below.

```
MAIN CLASS:
package com.example.alarmdemo;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    EditText homeworkBar;
    DatabaseHandler db;

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    /* Called when the acitivity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_time);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        homeworkBar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Homework);

        textAlarmPrompt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }


        });
    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                AndroidTimeActivity.this,
                onTimeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        if(calSet.compareTo(calNow)<=0){
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);



        /* CONVERSION TO STRING TO BE SAVED IN DATABASE */
        int hours = calSet.getTime().getHours();
        int mins = calSet.getTime().getMinutes();

        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";


        String minutes = "";
        if (mins < 10)
            minutes = "0" + mins;
        else
            minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

        // Append in a StringBuilder
       String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

        String getHW = homeworkBar.getText().toString();

        db.addHW(getHW, aTime);
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Homework Alarm is set!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


    }

};


    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

        int hour = targetCal.getTime().getHours();
        int minute = targetCal.getTime().getMinutes();

           String timeSet = "";
            if (hour > 12) {
                hour -= 12;
                timeSet = "PM";
            } else if (hour == 0) {
                hour += 12;
                timeSet = "AM";
            } else if (hour == 12)
                timeSet = "PM";
            else
                timeSet = "AM";


            String minutes = "";
            if (minute < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minute;
            else
                minutes = String.valueOf(minute); 

            // Append in a StringBuilder
           String TimeToString = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(':')
                    .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString(); 

           db = new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());
           Cursor cursor = db.returnData();

           /* REQUEST CODE FOR MULTIPLE ALARMS */
           int requestcode = 0;
           if(cursor.moveToFirst())
           {
               do{                  
                   if(TimeToString.equals(cursor.getString(1)))
                   {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), requestcode++, intent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                        textAlarmPrompt.setText( "\n\n***\n"
                                 + "Alarm is set@" + TimeToString + "\n"
                                 + "***\n"); 
                   }
               }while(cursor.moveToNext());
           }

    }



}

Alarm Receiver class:
package com.example.alarmdemo;



import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String HOMEWORK = "com.example.alarm.ACTION";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        generateNotification(context,"What's your next homework?");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (HOMEWORK.equals(action)) {
            //do what you want here
            generateNotification(context,"What's your next homework?");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
          System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2");
          int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
          long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
          String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
          String subTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Output.class);
          notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);
          PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0 ,notificationIntent, 0);
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

          notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
          //To play the default sound with your notification:
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
          notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
          notificationManager.notify(0, notification);



    }

}


DATABASE HANDLER CLASS:
package com.example.alarmdemo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TheDataBase";

    private static final String TABLE_HOMEWORK = "homework";



    SQLiteDatabase db;


    //Columns for Homework table 

        public static final String HOMEWORK = "subject";
        public static final String TIME = "time";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    //to create the tables
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        //String CREATE_MEDICATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TABLE_MEDICATION(MEDICINES)";
        String CREATE_SCHEDULE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HOMEWORK + "(" 
                + HOMEWORK + " TEXT," + TIME + " TEXT" + ")"; 

        db.execSQL(CREATE_SCHEDULE_TABLE);
        System.out.println("Tables created");
    }


    //to upgrade the database
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HOMEWORK);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addHW(String hw, String when){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(HOMEWORK, hw);
        values.put(TIME, when);

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_HOMEWORK, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor returnData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_HOMEWORK, new String[]{HOMEWORK, TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }



}



package com.example.alarmdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Output extends Activity{
    TextView textmessage;
     String stringValue;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_output);

      textmessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      stringValue = intent.getStringExtra("content");
      textmessage.setText(stringValue);
      System.out.println(stringValue);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its likely because

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), requestcode++, intent, 0);
```

you are incrementing it by one but not reassigning the value.

Simplify it by this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), requestcode, intent, 0);

requestcode+=1;
```